# Changing the orientation of Buttons in Android app

Tags: android, button, grid-layout, layout-gravity

I'm designing a GUI for android game. So far I designed this

[image]

this is my code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Start"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:rowCount="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nG"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:background="@drawable/red"
            android:onClick="nGame"
            android:text="New" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hS"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@drawable/green"
            android:onClick="hScore"
            android:text="High Scores" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/a"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@drawable/blue"
            android:onClick="about"
            android:text="About" />

    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

but i want to look my UI like this

[image]

I tried to do this using android:gravity. but I was unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **RelativeLayout** for achieving this. Also you could add a empty view first in your xml file(first child). Like this:

```
<View android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
```

Empty spaces tend to take all the available space. So the space remaining after keeping the buttons would be consumed by this view.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use layout_gravity. Just use

`android:gravity="bottom"`